# RunTime Error at setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Tags: android, kotlin, setcontentview

So I'm getting an exception on my Android App, that I have no idea where comes from. And yes my code is a complete mess now from trying to fix it

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var navigationDrawerIconsList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    var images_for_navdrawer= intArrayOf(R.drawable.navigation_allsongs,R.drawable.navigation_favorites,R.drawable.navigation_settings,R.drawable.navigation_aboutus)
    object statified{
        var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout?=null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        MainActivity.statified.drawerLayout= findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navigationDrawerIconsList.add("All Songs")
        navigationDrawerIconsList.add("Favourites")
        navigationDrawerIconsList.add("Settings")
        navigationDrawerIconsList.add("About Us")

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this@MainActivity, MainActivity.statified.drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        MainActivity.statified.drawerLayout?.setDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        val mainScreenFragment = MainScreenFragment()
        this.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.details_fragment,mainScreenFragment,"MainScreenFragment")
                .commit()
        var _navigationAdapter= NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationDrawerIconsList,images_for_navdrawer,this)
        _navigationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        var navigation_recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.navigation_recycler_view)
        navigation_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        navigation_recycler_view.itemAnimator=DefaultItemAnimator()
        navigation_recycler_view.adapter = _navigationAdapter
        navigation_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
    }
}
```

My Main Activity XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/header">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/title"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Where I am getting following errors while running the application 
while testing application using the device, I got errors in Logcat of Android Studio.

```
   04-22 15:11:07.104 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    04-22 15:11:08.253 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>
    04-22 15:11:08.259 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onDraw
    04-22 15:11:08.261 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
    04-22 15:11:08.262 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
    04-22 15:11:09.533 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 98010016-byte allocation.
    04-22 15:11:09.740 22545-22545/com.example.geeth.magnitude E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.geeth.magnitude, PID: 22545
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2166)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3596)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
            at com.example.geeth.magnitude.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your Java stack trace as text, in the question. We cannot see the full stack trace in that image, and other developers cannot search your image.

Comment: What is the size of your `@drawable/title` image?

Comment: Your drawable resources are too large. Use a library like Glide or Picasso instead to load them in the Kotlin code

Comment: question is edited @CommonsWare

Comment: size of @drawable/title is 3300x3300 and it is png format @Reaz Murshed

Comment: As answered below, I think you need to pick a smaller size. However, you may consider putting the image file into `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder and check if its still crashing.

Comment: That drawable is much too large. There is no 3300x3300 screen used in Android today. Plus, even that would not explain a 98010016 byte allocation, as 3300x3300 would result in about a 43560000-byte allocation. Create a smaller image. Also, if you wish to use this image for all screen densities, put it in `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the drawable that you are setting in your `ImageView` is too large. Please pick an image with smaller size to avoid the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Please check the `@drawable/title` size as mentioned in the comment.

To get the idea about the image sizes, I would recommend to read this [beautiful article here](https://android.jlelse.eu/navigation-drawer-styling-under-material-design-f0767882e692).

Comment: Can you tell mean what is the minimum size for image to keep as header @Reaz Murshed

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Once you get the idea about dp, you will understand what the maximum size of your image should be.